# Why would I need to check for greater than Int32.MaxValue?

Tags: c#, .net

I am using Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Ultimate on a c# class library project (.net 4) and I am curious about something...

Given this method:

```
public void DoSomethingBrilliant(int input)
{
    if (input == int.MaxValue)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("input");

    input++;

    Console.WriteLine(input);
}
```

I get this warning from code analysis:

> > CA2233 : Microsoft.Usage : Correct the potential overflow in the operation 'input+1' in 'Test.DoSomethingBrilliant(int)'.

I thought to myself, that is a bit odd since I am checking that the `input++` operation won't overflow by throwing that snazzy exception at the beginning but I changed it to this:

```
public void DoSomethingBrilliant(int input)
{
    if (input >= int.MaxValue)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("input");

    input++;

    Console.WriteLine(input);
}
```

and sure enough the warning went away.

Now my little brain is all confused because given I am getting an [int](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.aspx) as an argument why would checking to see if it is greater than the maximum value allowed for an integer ever provide any value?

Then I went back to the original bit of code and switched to debug and it built without the warning!  Curiouser and curioser...

I checked the differences between debug and release and found that if I tick the *Optimize code* option the warning from code analysis pops right back up.

So the optimization results in something that means I need to check for greater than [int.MaxValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue.aspx).  Huh?  Why?  Am I being super dense?  What has the optimization done that means I might get an int bigger than [int.MaxValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue.aspx) passed into a method accepting an [int](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.aspx)?

Or, is this just a bug in the code analysis feature?

**Update**

Here is the IL for the "unoptimized" version (where the code analysis gets it right):

```
.method public hidebysig instance void  DoSomethingBrilliant(int32 input) cil managed
{
  // Code size       40 (0x28)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init ([0] bool CS$4$0000)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldarg.1
  IL_0002:  ldc.i4     0x7fffffff
  IL_0007:  ceq
  IL_0009:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_000a:  ceq
  IL_000c:  stloc.0
  IL_000d:  ldloc.0
  IL_000e:  brtrue.s   IL_001b
  IL_0010:  ldstr      "input"
  IL_0015:  newobj     instance void [mscorlib]System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException::.ctor(string)
  IL_001a:  throw
  IL_001b:  ldarg.1
  IL_001c:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_001d:  add
  IL_001e:  starg.s    input
  IL_0020:  ldarg.1
  IL_0021:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
  IL_0026:  nop
  IL_0027:  ret
} // end of method Test::DoSomethingBrilliant
```

and here it is for the optimized version (where it gets it wrong):

```
.method public hidebysig instance void  DoSomethingBrilliant(int32 input) cil managed
{
  // Code size       31 (0x1f)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ldarg.1
  IL_0001:  ldc.i4     0x7fffffff
  IL_0006:  bne.un.s   IL_0013
  IL_0008:  ldstr      "input"
  IL_000d:  newobj     instance void [mscorlib]System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException::.ctor(string)
  IL_0012:  throw
  IL_0013:  ldarg.1
  IL_0014:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0015:  add
  IL_0016:  starg.s    input
  IL_0018:  ldarg.1
  IL_0019:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
  IL_001e:  ret
} // end of method Test::DoSomethingBrilliant
```

I see a bunch of extra calls before the throw operation but I am going to be honest - I have no idea what they do!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Or, is this just a bug in the code analysis feature?

Looks like it. Not terribly surprising, to be honest - getting this sort of code analysis to be perfect is mightily tricky. Given that any particular `int` *cannot* be greater than `int.MaxValue`, `>=` and `==` are definitely equivalent.

Comment: The code analyzer probably sees the inequality operators as having more gravitas than simple equality. I certainly try to chop off as much of the universe of values when I do safety checks.

Comment: I am interested why it would get it right on a non-optimized "debug" assembly?

Comment: @kmp: Wouldn't like to say. I wonder whether `==` is optimized in some odd way. Have you looked at the IL at all?

Comment: Yeah, I did look at the IL but I am not really any the wiser (as I don't really understand IL) - I stuck it in the question just for completeness.

Comment: +1.  Most likely, the code analysis is looking at the execution flow without inlining `int.MaxValue`, so it has no idea that the value being compared to is truly the maximum value for an `Int32`.

Answer (score 1):

See these code fragments:

```
if (x == int.MaxValue) return;
// x != int.MaxValue
```

and

```
if (x >= int.MaxValue) return;
// x < int.MaxValue
```

and

```
// x < int.MaxValue
// rewrite
// x + 1 <= int.MaxValue
x++;
// x <= int.MaxValue
```

The postcondition of x++ shows (by derivation) that 
the precondition has to be:

```
x < int.MaxValue
```

which can only be established in case you check:

```
x >= int.MaxValue
```